# Remove/Edit Range onclick text in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

Was wondering how you can remove/edit the textbox that appears in the browser Edge when you manually change a range input's value. Preferably with HTML/CSS or JavaScript.

[image: The textbox that should be removed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `::-ms-tooltip` pseudo-element to remove the value text. I'm not sure if you can style it anyway you want, though as [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465805.aspx) reads:

> Note that only display and visibility style properties are applicable for an -ms-tooltip.

Here is a sample with the tooltip removed:

```css
input[type="range"]::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" />
```